# Localization not working on dotnet6 aspnet alpine docker image

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, localization

I have an application that need to translate date. When using VS2022, I'm able to switch between languages when changing a entry parameter. When I run the docker container containing my app, dates are not localized and only English is supported by default

Here my dockerfile :
`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY myApp/. .
RUN dotnet restore myApp.sln
WORKDIR /src/myApp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT false
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]
```

`

I also tried by switching
`

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT false
```

`

When executing
myDate.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")), the date is returned in english instead of french

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that icu-libs no longer contains all cultures.

You need to add:
`RUN apk add --no-cache icu-data-full`

For more information, take a look here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3844